# How to enable copy initialization for explicit overloaded constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I assume making overloaded constructor `explicit` prevent copy initialization, what if I do need it to be `explicit` how can I enable copy initialization for the following class

```
class real {
public:
    explicit real(const double& value) : x(value) {}
    real(const real& other) : x(other.x) {}
    ~real() = default;

    real& operator= (const double& rhs) {
        this->x = rhs; 
        return *this;
    }

    operator double() {
        return this->x;
    }
private:
    double x;
};

int main(){

    real r1 = 3.4;  // Error
    real r2 = (real) 3.4;   // Ok : is this the only way ?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good C++:

```
real r2 = (real) 3.4;
```

What you want is this:

```
real r2(3.4);
```

That's the usual way to pass arguments to a constructor in C++.  That's what people would expect to see when they read your code.

If you have a case where you need to assign, you can do this:

```
r2 = real(3.4);
```

Comment: You mean I invoke copy constructor by creating temporary object instead of casting... this is good way dont know how I missed this ... but  I thought I could do direct assignment (copy initialization) without casting and without creating temporary object.

Comment: Right.  I don't think there will be adverse performance impact with an optimizing compiler anyway.